# Error: Undefined class constant 'MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY'

Tags: php, mysql, drupal, drupal-8

Currently I'm getting this kind of message and I don't know how to fix it.

The command `php -m` tells me that PDO and pdo_mysql are there.

I'm using Drupal-8 with php7.1.20 on Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS

> [Tue Sep 04 09:27:48.210064 2018] [php7:notice] [pid 2183] [client
>   10.56.99.1:53758] Error: Undefined class constant 'MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY' in
>   /var/www/dev/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Database/Driver/mysql/Connection.php
>   on line 134 #0
>   /var/www/dev/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Database/Database.php(376):
>   Drupal\Core\Database\Driver\mysql\Connection::open(Array)\n#1
>   /var/www/dev/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Database/Database.php(166):
>   Drupal\Core\Database\Database::openConnection('default',
>   'default')\n#2 [internal function]:
>   Drupal\Core\Database\Database::getConnection('default')\n#3
>   /var/www/dev/web/core/lib/Drupal/Component/DependencyInjection/PhpArrayContainer.php(79):
>   call_user_func_array('Drupal\\Core\\Dat...', Array)\n#4
>   /var/www/dev/web/core/lib/Drupal/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php(171):
>   Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\PhpArrayContainer->createService(Array,
>   'database')\n#5
>   /var/www/dev/web/core/lib/Drupal/Component/DependencyInjection/PhpArrayContainer.php(260):
>   Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->get('database',
>   1)\n#6
>   /var/www/dev/web/core/lib/Drupal/Component/DependencyInjection/PhpArrayContainer.php(62):
>   Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\PhpArrayContainer->resolveServicesAndParameters(Array)\n#7
>   /var/www/dev/web/core/lib/Drupal/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php(171):
>   Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\PhpArrayContainer->createService(Array,
>   'cache.container')\n#8
>   /var/www/dev/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/DrupalKernel.php(516):
>   Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->get('cache.container')\n#9
>   /var/www/dev/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/DrupalKernel.php(877):
>   Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->getCachedContainerDefinition()\n#10
>   /var/www/dev/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/DrupalKernel.php(469):
>   Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->initializeContainer()\n#11
>   /var/www/dev/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/DrupalKernel.php(665):
>   Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->boot()\n#12
>   /var/www/dev/web/index.php(19):
>   Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request))\n#13
>   {main}

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/project/dbtng_migrator/issues/1258942

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/installing-drupal/2011-01-06/drupal-7-php-fatal-error-undefined-class-constant-mysql

Comment: https://github.com/geerlingguy/drupal-vm/issues/226

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Nvm.

`apt-get install php-mysql` and a simple `service apache2 restart` fixed atleast that error.

Comment: I think this issue is more than well enough documented on the Drupal site and associated forums

Comment: I visited most of the links u put up. Adding any extensions didnt work for me

Comment: After lots of searching, this was the fix I needed. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you for documenting your solution!

Comment: Thank you! works for me

Comment: apt-get install php7.2-mysql worked for me. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In case of amazon linux below command to install extension should help

```
yum install php-mysqlnd
```

In my case it had happened while trying to re-install php-pdo. removal command did remove the dependencies php-mysqlnd and php-pgsql. Installation did not add those dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

This is what helped to me.

Just uncomment `extension=pdo_mysql` in `php.ini` and drush started to work:

[image]

Comment: Hi. Stack Overflow [discourages use of images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557) for code/error/debug/log messages. Images create problems for usability, readability, and searchabiilty among many other reasons. Please post the relevant content of the configuration file as text.